# HTML form post redirection error in specific browser

Tags: angularjs, redirect, war

I have to do a html form POST with certain parameters to a third party client.

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="https://www.thirparty.com.np/Retail/sgonHttpHandler.aspx?Action.ShoppingMall.Login.Init=Y">

  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="BankId" VALUE="004">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="MD" VALUE="P">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="PID" VALUE="000000003154">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="CRN" VALUE="NPR">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="RU" VALUE="http://shop/response_post.aspx?">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="CG" VALUE="N">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="USER_LANG_ID" VALUE="001">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="UserType" VALUE="1">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="AppType" VALUE="retail">
  <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="PAY">
</FORM>
```

This form works fine when using it as a standalone html file. But when we put it inside our application, which is in angularJs. The form does not seem to work.

When using it in standalone, I get the following response from the server

```
Request URL: https://www.thirparty.com.np/Retail/sgonHttpHandler.aspx?Action.ShoppingMall.Login.Init=Y
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK

Request URL: https://www.thirparty.com.np/Retail/(S(nkqmntjneehv3kfv0yogfk55))/sgonHttpHandler.aspx?Action.ShoppingMall.Login.Init=Y
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found

Request URL: https://www.thirparty.com.np/Retail/(S(nkqmntjneehv3kfv0yogfk55))/web/L001/retail/jsp/ebpp/RetShoppingMallSignOn.aspx?RequestId=41373058
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

The third url is where it is supposed to go, i.e a login page.

But when done from within the application we get

```
Request URL: https://www.thirparty.com.np/Retail/sgonHttpHandler.aspx?Action.ShoppingMall.Login.Init=Y
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found

Request URL: https://www.thirparty.com.np/Retail/(S(b3w11s45wtji1vbdx3grrc45))/sgonHttpHandler.aspx?Action.ShoppingMall.Login.Init=Y
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found

Request URL: https://www.thirparty.com.np/Retail/(S(b3w11s45wtji1vbdx3grrc45))/web/errsetup.aspx?RequestId=50835532
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

The first response from the form POST is

> 302 Found

While when using the html form as a standalone it returns

> 200 OK

Why is it so? The third party site has not done anything for security. So it does not seem to be caused due to the IP not being white listed.

**EDIT**

The one thing that was found out that, the form was submitted as a **document** type when using standalone html file. But when used from inside the application, the form was sent was **text**.

Comment: Did you copy the form exactly in your app?  No ajax / no variables?

Comment: @Dan yesI did, not ajax no extra variables.